# Putting the parentheses on the print statement

Tags: python

I am tired of putting parentheses in this code it is a long code but they miss to put parentheses next to print statement help me to solve this problem show some way that a program can automatically put parentheses if it is not presented.

#### Change False to True to see Numpy arrays in action

```
if True:
    array = np.array([1, 4, 5, 8], float)
    print array
    print ""
    array = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], float)  # a 2D array/Matrix
    print array
```

Answer (score 0):

One option to cleanup your Python 2.x print statements into proper function calls would be to try the following regex replacement from your IDE:

```
Find:    \bprint (\S+)
Replace: print($1)
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

The code that you're sending here is Python 2.x. Back then `print` was considered a statement, and parentheses were not needed. This changed with Python 3, however, as `print` became a function. Consequently, the above code will not run successfully. You need to run this code with the Python 2 interpreter, or you can use the following regex in your IDE:

```
Find: \bprint (\S+)
Replace: print($1)
```

If your IDE does not support regex matching, then you can use `2to3` to convert Python 2 to Python 3 code (https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html). Alternatively you may have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using 2to3, which is included with Python 3 installations. The idea is that you point it at a Python2 script, and it takes a stab at transforming it into Python3. You call it something like this:

```
2to3 -w my_script.py
```

Worth backing everything up before you start, just in case. More details are available [in the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html).

There's also an [online tool you could try](https://www.pythonconverter.com/).